# Move Search to the Category view

Tags: frontend, catalogsearch

I would like to move the search facility from the header.phtml, to the category view page. Looking at other posts I have created the following entry in my local.xml file:

```
  <reference name="root">
        <block type="core/template" name="top.search" as="topSearch" template="catalogsearch/form.mini.phtml"/>
    </reference>
```

And in app\design\frontend\default{Theme Name}\template\catalog\category\view.phtml

I have the following:

```
  <?php  echo $this->getChildHtml('topSearch') ?>
```

Am I doing something wrong?

EDIT:

Full local.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
<default>

  <remove name="checkout.cart.coupon"></remove>
  <remove name="checkout.cart.shipping"></remove>

</default>

<catalog_category_default>
 <reference name="header">
     <action method="unsetChild"><name>top.search</name></action>
 </reference>
 <reference name="category.products">
     <action method="insert"><block>top.search</block></action>
 </reference>
</catalog_category_default>
<catalog_category_layered>
  <reference name="header">
     <action method="unsetChild"><name>top.search</name></action>
 </reference>
 <reference name="category.products">
     <action method="insert"><block>top.search</block></action>
 </reference>
 </catalog_category_layered>

 <catalogsearch_result_index translate="label">
  <label>Quick Search Form</label>
  <reference name="root">
      <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
  </reference>
 </catalogsearch_result_index>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need to add the block to the correct parent. You mentioned the template `catalog/category/view.phtml` so working from this information you will need the handles `catalog_category_default` and `catalog_category_layered`. The parent block has the name `category.products` in both cases.

```
<catalog_category_default>
    <reference name="header">
        <action method="unsetChild"><name>top.search</name></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="category.products">
        <action method="insert"><block>top.search</block></action>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_default>
<catalog_category_layered>
    <reference name="header">
        <action method="unsetChild"><name>top.search</name></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="category.products">
        <action method="insert"><block>top.search</block></action>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_layered>
```

What this will do is remove the search from the header and add it to the category products block as a child, you can then call `getChildHtml` in your template.

Comment: Just tried your suggestion it don't work either. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @user9252 what actually happened? Did it just do nothing?

Comment: it did nothing.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is very old, but I gonna post my awnser hopping it can help others with this same problem

In my case, I needed another search form on my footer so I opened

app/desing/frontend/base/default/layout/catalogsearch.xml

and copied:

```
<reference name="header">
        <block type="core/template" name="top.search" as="topSearch" template="catalogsearch/form.mini.phtml"/>
    </reference>
```

to: app/desing/frontend/my-theme/my-theme/layout/local.xml inside the default tags

```
<reference name="header">
        <block type="core/template" name="top.search" as="topSearch" template="catalogsearch/form.mini.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</default><!-- just to give a idea of the position of where you should paste this code -->
```

and then I changed it to:

```
<reference name="footer">
        <block type="core/template" name="footer.search" as="footerSearch" template="catalogsearch/form.mini.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</default>
```

then in my footer file I called:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('footerSearch') ?>
```

basically you have to tell where your theme needs to get the 'footerSearch' using the local xml, then you can call it thought php.